# Jquery .load() html content without wrapping it to a div

Tags: jquery

For example this wraps the content of the test.html into the .wrapper , but i want to add the content of the html next to an existing div without wrapping it contents.

```
$( "#button" ).click(function() {
    $( ".wrapper" ).load( "test.html" );
});
```

Comment: _"but i want to add the content of the html next to an existing div without wrapping it contents."_ Why do you call `$( ".wrapper" ).load( "test.html" );`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `.after` and cannot use `.load()` for this:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
  $.get("test.html", function (res) {
    $("selector-for-existing-div").after(res);
  });
});
```

Let's say I want to put this after the `h1` here:

```js
$(function () {
  $("#button").click(function() {
    $.get("https://api.github.com/", function (res) {
      $("h1").after(res.current_user_url);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<input id="button" value="Click Me!" type="button" />
```